# Show an autonumber ID when creating a item in a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'd like to know how to show a non-editable id when a user adds an item to a list. I was thinking about a workflow but i don't know how to approach this issue. It must show the ID in the form that creates the new item.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible as SharePoint item is created when is saved into database and his ID is generated within the save operation. In the new item form (typically newForm.aspx) is not accessible.